# Perform ssh on solaris 10 using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, solaris, paramiko

I was trying to perform ssh in a python code using Paramiko, it worked on my local machine.
when I uploaded it to the server (SOLARIS 10), I Downloaded Paramiko from pipit.org and pip install it but It requires cryptography library

```
Collecting cryptography>=2.5 (from paramiko==2.7.2)
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/cryptography/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography>=2.5 (from paramiko==2.7.2) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cryptography>=2.5 (from paramiko==2.7.2)
```

and cryptography don't offer **py2.py3-none-any.whl**

I've tried to install the source code of cryptography as well but I had no luck with that any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try install netmiko library it comes along with the cryptography lib as well as with